# Symfony 4.4.26 Sonata Admin. Formatter widget doesn't work

Tags: php, twig, symfony4, sonata-admin

I use `sonata-project/formatter-bundle ^4.5`.
In my NewsAdmin.php I want to create SimpleFormatterType:

```
$formMapper->add('body', SimpleFormatterType::class, [
            'format' => 'richhtml',
        ]);
```

My sonata_admin.yaml:

```
templates:
        layout: '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig'
```

My `templates/bundles/SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/skins/sonata/style.css') }}" type="text/css"
          media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/style.css') }}"
          type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/style.css') }}" type="text/css"
          media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/style.css') }}" type="text/css"
          media="all"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/ivoryckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/vendor/markitup-markitup/markitup/jquery.markitup.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

My fos_ckeditor.yaml:

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
fos_ck_editor:
  configs:
    news: ~
```

After all these manipulations nothing has changed. I still see default text area without any editing tools.